# combination maker for lists of different length with nested for loops and not intertools

Tags: python

So I'm trying to get a handle on nested for loops in python, so i'm making a combination maker that loops until it finds the right combination of letters, numbers, and special characters.  I know that intertools is the easiest way to do this, but I need to get a better understanding of how the nested for loops work.  Here is how I would like the code to function.

a

b

c

...

1

2

3

...

~

@

#

...

A

B

C

...

aa

ab

ac

so on and so forth.

it continues to go through the lists I have until the correct set of characters.  it will end up being quite a number of iterations by the end of it.

Here is my code

```
# this program is a password cracker that uses loops to find an appropriate character.
# It is capable of using numbers, letters, basic symbols, capitol letters, and up to 8 characters.
# It checks the whole list at once against the other whole list


lowalpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
        'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
upalpha = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
       'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
special = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '~', '?']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
hiddenpass = ['D', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'k', 'c', 'o', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'e']

i = len(hiddenpass)
password = ['']*i

low = 0
up = 0
sp = 0
num = 0
X = 0
Y = 0
Z = 1


   def iterator():
        global low, up, sp, num, X, password, lowalpha, upalpha, special, numbers
        for low in range(len(lowalpha)):
            password[X] = lowalpha[low]
        for up in range(len(upalpha)):
            password[X] = upalpha[up]
        for sp in range(len(special)):
            password[X] = special[sp]
        for num in range(len(numbers)):
            password[X] = numbers[num]


if password != hiddenpass:
    for Y in range(len(password)):
        for Z in range(len(lowalpha)):
            password[Y] = lowalpha[Z]
            iterator()
            X = X + 1
        low = 0
        up = 0
        sp = 0
        num = 0
        X = 0
        Y = 0
        Z = 1
        for Z in range(len(upalpha)):
            password[Y] = upalpha[Z]
            iterator()
            X = X + 1
        low = 0
        up = 0
        sp = 0
        num = 0
        X = 0
        Y = 0
        Z = 1
        for Z in range(len(special)):
            password[Y] = special[Z]
            iterator()
            X = X + 1
        low = 0
        up = 0
        sp = 0
        num = 0
        X = 0
        Y = 0
        Z = 1
        for Z in range(len(numbers)):
            password[Y] = numbers[Z]
            iterator()
            X = X + 1
else:
    print('got em')
```

As of right now this does not work and fails the first time `iterator()` is called.  it fails at `password[X] = lowalpha[low]` inside that function.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mjf5.jpg Here is the error code.

Comment: What is the question? Are you trying to say that the code you have is too slow? Doesn't work or something else?

Comment: @PaulRooney As of right now the code does not work.  it has a problem with my `iterator()` function.  specifically `password[X] =lowalpha[low]`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test with all combinations due to my processor heating issue but i can give you little idea what you are looking for :

```
import sys

lowalpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
        'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
upalpha = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
       'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

def repeat(*args, repeat=3):
    result_1 = [tuple(i) for i in args] * repeat



    final_list=[[]]

    for i in result_1:
        copy_final=final_list

        final_list=[]

        for j in copy_final:

            for k in i:
                find=([k]+j)
                if find==['a','n','k']:
                    print("Here is find",find)
                    sys.exit()



                final_list.append(find)






repeat(lowalpha,lowalpha)
```

Comment: do you think you could walk me through your code.  I'm not very familiar with how you laid things out.  That, and I don't know what's from sys and what's not.  If you could go through and add comments that would help a ton.  This code works, but I don't quite understand it.

Comment: @Keizzerweiss sys.exit() is just for termination of program when condition found, you can continue loop if you are interested. And let me know where you are not getting code so i can add comments and can provide help to you.

Comment: @PaulAyodhyankit okay I'll have to sit down and really try to figure out what I can when I have time.  I guess let's talk about your `repeat()` function.  What does this do exactly, and what is your thought process when you made it.  if I can follow your logic it will help me a ton.

Comment: @Keizzerweiss if my solution works for you, You can accept my answer. Thanks :)